# How to get all addresses - including the "change" addresses - from bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoind, address, change

I want to get all my addresses - *including the auto-generated "change" addresses* - from a running bitcoind somehow.

I haven't been able to do it in a simple way. "getaddressesbyaccount" and all the other API options are only listing the "public" addresses and sometimes few additional ones, but never the already used change addresses. Can I do that somehow?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`listaddressgroupings`

I used the command `listaddressgroupings` from the bitcoin-qt console window and it listed all my addresses.  I then looked for one of my old send transactions here:

https://blockchain.info/

And found the change address.  It matches one of the addresses in the list.

Comment: I think you are correct. I will let you know and accept this if this is indeed correct.

Comment: I did that and there's nothing in my groupings.

Comment: When I use that command, I see every address that I've ever used.  Are you sure that the wallet is loaded?  It shows other tranactions and non-change addresses?  You can find your change addresses by looking up your addresses on blockchain.info

Comment: This also showed me the balance of each address, which was precisely what I needed.

Comment: is this only working when the address was linked to an account? edit: or do i have to complete syncing the chain? atm listaddressgroupings returns an emty array even though I called getnewaddress several times

Comment: I wish the GUI app would show these addresses!

Comment: This only shows used addresses in your wallet. The proper command is `listreceivedbyaddress 0 true` which lists all addresses in your wallet regardless of whether or not they have been used.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use [pywallet](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Pywallet) to get these.

Download a more updated version [here](https://github.com/jackjack-jj/pywallet).

Answer (score 1):

The proper command is `$ bitcoin-cli listreceivedbyaddress 0 true`. It will list all addresses in your wallet, regardless of have being used or not

This answer was originally a comment by [CR](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/69675/cr) to Eyal's answer