# In the basic Wallet based in QT, How can i get by RPC the stored addresses and labels?

Tags: blockchain, wallet, json-rpc

this question is for you to ask about the QT wallet, in the section to send coins, there is an address window, and it has the list of the stored addresses we save along the time. So using RPC, do you know if there is a way to obtain this data from inside? i am not refering myself on creating a new address or getaddresses by account command, i mean all the addresses we save, independently if they are ours or not.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I know of is

```
listreceivedbyaddress 0 true
```

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list says:

> Listing the bitcoin addresses in your wallet is easily done via listreceivedbyaddress. It normally lists only addresses which already have received transactions, however you can list all the addresses by setting the first argument to 0, and the second one to true.

---

Similar questions (different answers)

- [How to get all addresses - including the "change" addresses - from bitcoind?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9077/13866)