# Receive bitcoin before block downloading is finished

Tags: synchronization

here's the story:

I've downloaded Bitcoin v0.8.5-beta and bought myself some bitcoins before the block downloading was finished. Now the downloading is still not finished (3 days and counting): 250k and a bit with a rate of 100 an hour or so. I' ve got a bit of an older computer so that's probably not helping.

Question: will I ever see my bitcoins and/or is there another way to transfer it to another wallet? Or is there a way to download the blocks faster?

I'm fearing that the rate of blocks created is higher then the download rate of my computer...

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using thin client, like Multibit. Your balance will be available to you after few second. You can import BitcoinQT wallet in no time.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in your case:

- download a Multibit client
- import your "official" bitcoin wallet.dat into blockchain.info web wallet, as described here - [How do I import private keys from Bitcoin-qt to Multibit client?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5324/how-do-i-import-private-keys-from-bitcoin-qt-to-multibit-client)
- transfer to the multibit address

Bitcoin-qt is notoriously slow.