# Need help! Initial sync not progressing, BTC sent already, + warning message

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, receiving, message

Please help! I look forward to your intelligent caring responses.
Here is the situation:
I'm trying to do the initial synchronizing of Bitcoin-QT, which hasn't progressed in 14 hours, and:
- Significant BTC has already been sent to an address generated by the wallet.
- My primary objective is to receive the BTC that was sent to me. If Multibit is a sufficiently secure/etc wallet alternative, I do not care about completing the sync process in order to use Bitcoin-QT **** - I just want to effectively receive the BTC that has already been sent.****

Here is the problem:

- For the past 14 hours, there has been NO progress in the synchronization (after some progress in the time proceeding that). (The # of blocks processed has stayed the same, but the estimate of total blocks fluctuates - what i mean is, where it says "Processed 'x' of 'y' (estimated) blocks of transaction history" - the 'x' (i.e. blocks actually processed) has stayed the same for 14 hrs, the 'y' of estimated total blocks has fluctuated (sometimes larger, sometimes smaller).) - The golden arrow wheel on the bottom right is also not turning at all.
- Also the following warning message is at the top of the Overview page: "Warning: Displayed transactions may not be correct! You may need to upgrade, or other nodes may need to upgrade."

Background on this: the whole synchronization was started over 24 hours ago, but in the middle of night Bitcoin-QT crashed. (I think the warning message appeared after the program crashed & was restarted.) Whenever I restart Bitcoin-QT, it takes 5 minutes of rainbow-wheel loading on "verifying blocks" on initial bitcoin-version screen.

(other info if relevant to resolving this: the machine is a Mac, Snow Leopard; Bitcoin-QT v.0.8.5-beta
-- The progress bar shows about 1/8th complete. That has also not budged in 14 hours.
-- I did try this on a different and faster internet connection/network for about 5 hours with same result except the last bar on the right did not go green like on my regular internet connection.
-- I do have the original .dmg download file if that's of any help.
-- I have restarted both Bitcoin-QT and the computer a # of times.
-- When the progress was actually happening yesterday before the program crashed, the arrow-wheel was turning and there was no warning message.)

So basically the questions are:

- Is it actually synchronizing even though there have been NO signs of further progress for at least 14 hours & a Warning message has appeared?
- **What is the most effective - and secure - way for me to actually receive the BTC that were sent to me to this Bitcoin-QT wallet-generated address? Should I ditch trying to synchronize and try to receive them through something like Multibit? (Even if the initial sync ends up happening I will likely ditch Bitcoin-QT anyway for something like Multibit, as long as it is sufficiently secure.)**

Your help is appreciated! Neither the sender nor receiver of these bitcoins wants them to be lost due some sort of synchronizing malfunction, if that is what's going on.
I look forward to hearing from you, oh intelligent caring knowledgeable BTC users.

Comment: You won't see your BTC in your wallet until it processes the blockchain up to the point when such amounts were sent to you - be patient or switch to Multibit/Electrum or an online wallet.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to switch to Multibit, you can get the private key from the Bitcoin-Qt wallet using the debug console:  Help -> Debug Window -> Console.  Enter the command:

dumpprivkey public-address

This will list the private key associated with the public address you used to send the coins to your wallet.  You can then import this private key into a Multibit wallet by following this [guide](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5324/how-do-i-import-private-keys-from-bitcoin-qt-to-multibit-client) to import a private key into Multibit.

If you want to keep using Bitcoin-Qt, you can download the initial blockchain and then start Bitcoin-Qt to synchronize with the network.  Go [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoinblockchain/files) to download the initial blockchain.  Delete the 'blocks' and 'chainstate' folders in the bitcoin data directory and then unpack the downloaded file in the bitcoin data directory.  Start Bitcoin-Qt and it will rebuild the blockchain and then synchronize with the network.

The bitcoin data directory can be found [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory),

Comment: (regarding the 2nd suggestion for Bitcoin-QT, the synchronization did make some initial progress, but is now apparently stalled, so i don't know how that would work.)