# How to import old wallet to Multibit?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, multibit, wallet.dat, wallet-recovery

I had 2 Bitcoins on my old PC and got a virus so did a format.
But I also did a backup of my bitcoin wallet.
Now I want to sell these bitcoins but when I went to the site, the official client was different and very heavy. And the site was showing as first option Multibit.

So, I got Multibit. But I couldn't import the old .dat wallet.
Am I missing something? Is there any way to convert the wallet for Multibit?

Is this safe? 
https://blockchain.info/wallet/import-wallet

Answer (score 1):

Yes, blockchain.info's wallet import is safe. It [encrypts things](https://blockchain.info/wallet/wallet-faq) in such a way that not even blockchain.info can access your private keys. You can make transfers from there (it's a sort of online wallet), so you don't even necessarily need to transfer them to MultiBit before wanting to sell them.

To quote a [previous answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/5328/12034) with instructions on importing and then exporting to MultiBit:

> - Visit https://blockchain.info/wallet/import-wallet. Drag the Bitcoin-Qt wallet.dat file into the dotted area. Follow the
>     instructions.
> - Login to the new wallet. Under the Backup heading click download.
> - Open multibit choose Tools -> Import Private Keys. Now import the wallet.aes.json file just downloaded.
> - Delete the keys from the blockchain.info wallet.

If you don't trust blockchain.info (despite their claims), you could extract the data entirely offline using [pywallet](https://github.com/jackjack-jj/pywallet) and then import it into MultiBit.

It should also be possible to dump the private keys from the official client without downloading the whole blockchain (which is the "very heavy" part of it). See [How do I import private keys from Bitcoin-qt to Multibit client?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5324/how-do-i-import-private-keys-from-bitcoin-qt-to-multibit-client) for help with that.

Once you have access to your bitcoins again and want to sell them, you could sell them on [LocalBitcoins](https://localbitcoins.com/country/GR). In the US, I can also recommend [Coinbase](https://coinbase.com/).

Comment: ΟΚ, thanks. Can I also sell from the blockchain wallet? All I want to do is recover the bitcoins inmy old wallet and sell them. (although I don't know which site or method to trust)

Comment: @user10445 blockchain.info is not an exchange, so it won't buy your bitcoins or find you a buyer, but if you find a buyer another way, you can transfer from there. I've updated my answer. From your profile, it looks like you're in Greece; the only reputable place I know of other than in the US is [LocalBitcoins](https://localbitcoins.com/country/GR).

Comment: This doesn't work. It asks for me to enter a captcha, then enter the password for the wallet, and whether the password is correct or not, it doesn't show any error message or anything.

Answer (score 0):

What error did you get from Multibit? If its an error regarding to the file its maybe corrupted. I am not sure if you can import a .dat. I know for sure that a .wallet and .key will work, but not a .dat. Can you look inside with a text editor, and see whats in it?

Anyway the link you posted is as safe as it can be, so you can try that one. You can also try to import another file, like the .key or the .wallet if you still have those.