# How can I add an old Bitcoin wallet address from Bitcoin Core to MultiBit HD?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, address, import, multibit-hd

I have a wallet with Bitcoin Core.  I have used that address on various sites to receive payments from them.  I want to add that address to my account on my MultiBit HD program so it will just carry over to the new program but I cannot seem to figure out how to do it.  Please bear with me I am fairly new to all of this and I am still getting familiar with how things work.  Thank you in advance for any help you can offer

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I import private keys from Bitcoin-qt to Multibit client?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/5324/5406)