# What are the preferred UI images for Bitcoin Address & private key and multi-signature key?

Tags: development, private-key, public-key, multi-signature

How should I visually distinguish between the different types of keys available for the end user?

So far the common keys I've come across are

- Private key (not to be shared)
- Bitcoin address (to be shared, and may or may not have a backing private key)
- [Compressed public key](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3059/1878)
- [Casascius keys](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/User:Casascius/Passphrased_private_key_proposal) (where the private key is split in half totaling 3 keys)
- Multi signatures

Comment: I'm just looking for an official or preferred standard I can give to my graphic designer.  Lacking that she'll just come up with something based on Armory and QT.

Comment: Please do not use the term Public Key.   That isn't  a good term to describe what a Bitcoin address is.  It is a Bitcoin Address.

A Bitcoin Address is a hash of the private key, but calling it a public key is confusing it with PKI.

Programmers working on the code might use public key, but outside of that, Bitcoin Address is the preferred term.

Comment: @StephenGornick I updated references to public key and replaced with Bitcoin Address

Comment: Bitcoin is new, there isn't any recurring standard that I've seen. Come up with something interesting and it'll probably catch on