# Untypical input script

Tags: bitcoin-core, script, raw

There are many untypical `Input script` data in blockchain. What does it mean?

For example, transaction:

`4A253F17E5F4B24B41F72A6AE46DD1BCB25F7F33769C2AA5D50C6A6A7CF9F76E` ([link](https://blockchain.info/en/tx/4a253f17e5f4b24b41f72a6ae46dd1bcb25f7f33769c2aa5d50c6a6a7cf9f76e))

has it's input script:

`3046022100EE238CAD1E8AC7F14661760B1B1FB2CF171F41AFB31E3B59D3CED2284A1C2A71022100BEF7FB989CCFB00A65C009A77B46BC818D2E80458668F73DA0072966AAA28B620103B2ABE09A1C4E67C3EB9ACD5596452A5D785C6E5A772FBEA9A29CA95C15598EA6`

When I trying to parse this raw data, the result is:

`30`

`46`

`02`

`21`

`00EE238CAD1E8AC7F14661760B1B1FB2CF171F41AFB31E3B59D3CED2284A1C2A71` – Sig r

`02`

`21`

`00BEF7FB989CCFB00A65C009A77B46BC818D2E80458668F73DA0072966AAA28B62` – Sig s

`01`

`03`

`B2ABE09A1C4E67C3EB9ACD5596452A5D785C6E5A772FBEA9A29CA95C15598EA6` – **Unknown data**.

What is the unknown data? This is not a Public Key, but what is it?

P.S. I checked that this unknown data is not a part of public key (X coordinate of Public Key as I thinking). After calculating Y coordinate (on EC) of Public Key I get `9F203515694856269C76C797D8E8E784EBDB927B650705E348F6FBA07DC56FAF`. After I check the signature (Sig) with this:

`Public Key = B2ABE09A1C4E67C3EB9ACD5596452A5D785C6E5A772FBEA9A29CA95C15598EA6, 9F203515694856269C76C797D8E8E784EBDB927B650705E348F6FBA07DC56FAF`

`Transaction hash for this Sig = 59E4367A829551DE94594777789B9274BFBDAC9F66550B02B85639945F21BE3A`.

Then I calculate `x` and `y` from `Public Key`, `Hash` and generator point `G`. But `x` does not match the `Sig r` from raw data. So this way did not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a public key. I think you're parsing this transaction incorrectly - what you should get is that there are two elements. The first is a signature, and 73 bytes long, starting with `3046022100ee238c...` The second element is a public key, and 33 bytes long, and starts with `03b2abe09a1c4e67...`

---

Here's the transaction you linked, broken up into sig and pubkey.

version

```
01000000
```

vin count

```
01
```

outpoint

```
3abe215f943956b8020b55669facbdbf74929b7877475994de5195827a36e45900000000
```

script len

```
6c
```

push immediate 73 bytes

```
49
```

bytes

```
3046022100ee238cad1e8ac7f14661760b1b1fb2cf171f41afb31e3b59d3ced2284a1c2a71022100bef7fb989ccfb00a65c009a77b46bc818d2e80458668f73da0072966aaa28b6201
```

push immediate 33 bytes

```
21
```

bytes

```
03b2abe09a1c4e67c3eb9acd5596452a5d785c6e5a772fbea9a29ca95c15598ea6
```

sequence

```
ffffffff
```

(Everything below is part of the outputs.)

```
0206cfbb9f0f0000001976a914a66ba35c1d9bdcc8dfeb0fb8bedb16e1a570487d88ac09165612000000001976a914b420350a7b274e059d7ba5c97e8887d447b7287588ac00000000
```

Comment: Yeah, he's looking at already disassembled data. Not at the full script in hex.

Comment: The public key is a point wich has two 32b numbers, but this unknown data has only one number. There is no mistake, because I look at this data on the block explorer sites and it's the same as in my question.

Comment: @Denis This is a compressed key, which is a single 32b number and a single bit. See https://bitcoin.org/en/glossary/compressed-public-key and http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3059/what-is-a-compressed-bitcoin-key

Comment: @NickODell as I understand compressed key is the X coordinate of uncompressed key?

Comment: @Denis Yeah, that's right. See http://davidederosa.com/basic-blockchain-programming/elliptic-curve-keys/ for how to compress it.