# Converting xpub key to core format

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoind, public-key, xpub

I am experiencing some major issues which I honestly can't understand.
When I am generating a wallet from Electrum the public key looks like this: `xpub661MyMwAqRbcG8Zah6TcX3QpP5yJApaXcyLK8CJcZkuYjczivsHxVL5qm9cw8BYLYehgFeddK5WrxhntpcvqJKTVg96dUVL9P7hZ7Kcvqvd`

When I am generating a wallet address from bitcoin core rpc, the public key looks like this: `037acd3408dfb612a69204c5f5bafe2a326646398cdd16c85fedd65a4e96a28278`

When I am trying to create a multisig address in the core using this type of public keys, I get errror: `xpub661MyMwAqRbcG8Zah6TcX3QpP5yJApaXcyLK8CJcZkuYjczivsHxVL5qm9cw8BYLYehgFeddK5WrxhntpcvqJKTVg96dUVL9P7hZ7Kcvqvd`

When I am trying to create a multisig address in the core ( via PHP ) using this type of public keys, it works: `037acd3408dfb612a69204c5f5bafe2a326646398cdd16c85fedd65a4e96a28278`

I am super confused.

I am developing a multisig system for bitcoin, but it seems that I can't do it, since the clients will almost always use this type of public key generated from Electrum: `xpub661MyMwAqRbcG8Zah6TcX3QpP5yJApaXcyLK8CJcZkuYjczivsHxVL5qm9cw8BYLYehgFeddK5WrxhntpcvqJKTVg96dUVL9P7hZ7Kcvqvd`

Is there any type of conversion way in PHP from this type of public key:  `xpub661MyMwAqRbcG8Zah6TcX3QpP5yJApaXcyLK8CJcZkuYjczivsHxVL5qm9cw8BYLYehgFeddK5WrxhntpcvqJKTVg96dUVL9P7hZ7Kcvqvd` to this type: `037acd3408dfb612a69204c5f5bafe2a326646398cdd16c85fedd65a4e96a28278` ? 
I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong

Thank you for your time, and hope to get an answer!

Answer (score 6):

**The electrum public key** `xpub661MyMwAqRbcG8Zah6TcX3QpP5yJApaXcyLK8CJcZkuYjczivsHxVL5qm9cw8BYLYehgFeddK5WrxhntpcvqJKTVg96dUVL9P7hZ7Kcvqvd` is a [BIP32 extended public key](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#extended-keys). This can be used to derive child addresses.

**The Bitcoin-Core public key** `037acd3408dfb612a69204c5f5bafe2a326646398cdd16c85fedd65a4e96a28278` is a hex representation of the [compressed form of a public key](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3059/what-is-a-compressed-bitcoin-key).

In order to convert to from the extended to compressed format, all you need to do is decode from [Base58Check](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Base58Check_encoding) and grab the last 33 bytes (32 for private keys). I'm sure there's an implementation in PHP for Base58Check decoding. See [BIP32 - Extended Key Serialization](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#serialization-format):

`$ printf "xpub661MyMwAqRbcG8Zah6TcX3QpP5yJApaXcyLK8CJcZkuYjczivsHxVL5qm9cw8BYLYehgFeddK5WrxhntpcvqJKTVg96dUVL9P7hZ7Kcvqvd" | base58 -dc | xxd -p 0488b21e0000000000000000009f8b20f34eceef6ea60d35db00446763f7 dc76bd60ec8cf6fd63dc912499cbd4039edccce0e93f436a283947412378 8b33a28ed7ad7cffc3a130889f232344ad1c`

The last 33 bytes represent the hex version of the compressed public key (last 32 bytes for private keys).

`039edccce0e93f436a2839474123788b33a28ed7ad7cffc3a130889f232344ad1c`